# Why is Yarn build so slow?

Tags: typescript, yarn-v2

Recently, my build process became insanely slow - every container builds for 2-5 minutes. For every container, the slowest process is `RUN yarn build`. Nobody on the team experienced this (so, I am assuming it is something that affects only my machine), and it paralyzes my work since the project uses over a dozen containers (most of them are TypeScript-coded)

I am using an intel-based Mac. The longest-building container is frontend (React-based), but everything else is also very slow. What could cause it and how to fix it?

Comment: Restart your computer? Uninstall/reinstall yarn, docker (or whatever container software you're using? Remove containers and all of codebase, repull from GitHub (or whatever cloud git server)? Check your computer for a virus or rouge program eating up a bunch of memory/cpu?

Comment: Thank you. Turns out there was some issue with older images.
It was solved with 

$docker image prune

Comment: After prune, it still takes a lot of time. I performed yarn build locally and it takes only 17 secs compared to a 4 min build time inside docker.